# Network icon dropdown menu missing some items

Tags: 12.04, menu, indicator

There should be more staff in the dropdown menu. Sometimes a restart will solve the problem. I upgraded Ubuntu to 12.04.

[image: missing "connect to VPN etc."]

[image: and after a restart the indicator thinks I do not have Internet connection.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparently seems to be a bug. Found the bug report in launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1006141

Now  i didn't really found a solution but it's more like a workaround. It is easy to pop up a terminal and kill the nm-applet process and then restart it again. I dit it like this.

1. Look up the process:
   `ps -A | grep nm-applet`

3084 pts/0    00:00:00 nm-applet

1. Then kill the process:
   `kill 3084`
2. And then restart the applet:
   `nohup nm-applet &`

And this restarts your network applet and you will see the drop down menu.
Like a said it is not really a solution. So if you have found another way please let me know.